# When is it best to do an NSManagedObjectContext save?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5

I have noticed that for a mobile application, saving on the main thread seems to take a bit when it compares to other applications on the device. Is it recommended to only save Core Data when the application enters the background or when an application closes instead of anytime items are added and sent / received from the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of a broad question, but I've found that saving core data after VewDidAppear statements is better than viewWill statements. Giving the user something to engage with and persisting makes it less noticeable than on a load. However, if a user is used to waiting for something like an activity loop, adding the save to that doesn't tax it too much (IMHO).

Not sure this help, just my experience.

Comment: Is a save even needed if I am getting data from an API and using core data? Will storing it in memory be enough?

Comment: Enough for what? To have it persist when you reopen from background or have the data saved and re-accessed later? You can store something in just NSUserDefaults and it will persist as long as the user doesn't delete the app.